# Wireshark decrypt APNS traffic from curl

Tags: wireshark

I'm using php to connect to Apple's APN server, which uses TLSv1.2.

If I just start capturing packets to that host and send my push I see all the packets appear in the GUI for wireshark.  They're of course all encrypted though.  curl doesn't yet support the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable.

Is there any way that I can decode these packets?

The push is coming through just fine, but I'm basically trying to understand the HTTP/2 format a bit better and wanted to see exactly what's being written, vs. what I think would be written based on reading the RFC spec.

Answer (score 0):

> Since curl version 7.57.0 the SSLKEYLOGFILE feature can also be
>   enabled when built with GnuTLS, BoringSSL or OpenSSL. In the latter
>   two libs, the feature is powered by new APIs in those libraries and in
>   GnuTLS the library’s own logic similar to how NSS does it. Since
>   OpenSSL is the by far most popular TLS backend for curl, this feature
>   is now brought to users more widely.

https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/01/15/inspect-curls-tls-traffic/

Hopefully it's a matter of updating your curl :)